# stopped ssh, need way to connect again

Tags: ssh, connection, remote

i rented a virtual machine with ubuntu server. I logged in via the ssh-command in the terminal from my ubuntu home pc. Before i exited, i accidentally typed "stop ssh" in the terminal, because i thought it would end my ssh-session with the server. At the end "exit" did it - now i cant connect anymore to the server using "ssh user@host" with the error message:

ssh: connect to host HOSTNAME port 22: Connection refused

I think i shut down the ssh-module in the server. As an alternative connection way, i already tried the "sftp user@host" command, but in the end this command also tries to ssh to the server. As i rented this virtual machine, i don't have direct access to the servers file structure to change a configuration file or something like that. 
Is there any other way except ssh to connect to the server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have other means to reach the console of your VPS? Many hosting providers offer a console (via Ajaxterm or a Java applet) to reach the server if you locked yourself out. Please ask support with your hosting provider - we can't do anything from here, really.

Answer (score 1):

Is a VPS within a provider?

Reboot the server from the VPS control panel. Have your provider any tool to remotelly connect with the virtual server like the Lish terminal from Linode?, it works indenpendently from the server sshd.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to ask the owner of the VPS to either reboot the VPS or log in and restart the ssh server.